# Ane and her block toys

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Ane is a very smart kid.
She has 9 number blocks [1] to [9], and 2 operation block [+] and [x].
Today She is playing with her blocks.
She is so happy after arranging her blocks,
then perform the math operation, the result is 100000.

She even can create 2 operations.

```
[4][8][x][5][6][+][9][7][3][1][2] = 100000
[3][x][4][1][6][+][9][8][7][5][2] = 100000
```

She show it to her mother, then her mother challanges her to rearrange her blocks.
The result will still 100000, but she have to use 6 number blocks for multiplication, before addition.

What will her arrangement look like ?

Note : No other operation, just 1 multiplication and 1 addition.

Comment: Ane is smarter than me .. v.v

Comment: I want to congratulate everybody on the restraint they showed in not using <kbd>1</kbd> for blocks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer was found by a computer program.
For 3 digits x 3 digits + 3 digits:

> 158*627+934 = 100000
>  [1][5][8][x][6][2][7][+][9][3][4]
>  And if you consider the same numbers in different order a different arrangement (as @Rubio pointed out):
>  [6][2][7][x][1][5][8][+][9][3][4]

For 2 digits x 4 digits + 3 digits:

> 27*3698+154 = 100000
>  [2][7][x][3][6][9][8][+][1][5][4]
>  And if you consider the same numbers in different order a different arrangement (as @Rubio pointed out):
>  [3][6][9][8][x][2][7][+][1][5][4]

For 1 digit x 5 digits + 3 digits:

> There are no such arrangements

Comment: how come this was accepted but not upvoted? (+1/0 with my vote by the time of this comment)

Comment: I hope that it was coded in [Ana](http://ana.lmsal.com/)

Answer (score 4):

There are four solutions (found via computer):

> [1][5][8][×][6][2][7][+][9][3][4] = 100000     *(158 × 627 + 934)*
>  [2][7][×][3][6][9][8][+][1][5][4] = 100000     *(27 × 3698 + 154)*
>  [3][6][9][8][×][2][7][+][1][5][4] = 100000     *(3698 × 27 + 154)*
>  [6][2][7][×][1][5][8][+][9][3][4] = 100000     *(627 × 158 + 934)*

Comment: I would consider A x B + C is the same as B x A + C in which case there are two.

Comment: mathematically they are, but she's playing with blocks. i considered order relevant.

Comment: I think you are right so I added your reasoning to the accepted answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> 627*158+934

... which is equal to 100000.